# Midpoint of one side produced to be perpendicular to other vertex of a parallelogram.

Tags: geometry

In parallelogram ABCD, M is the midpoint of BC. DT is drawn from D perpendicular to MA. Prove CT = CD.

My attempt:-
I tried to do it with angles. I had to prove angle CTB = CBT. I am not able to get any idea.

This question was taken from the book **Challanging Problems in Geometry by Alfred Posamentier**

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have access to drawing tools right now so try to follow the description. Draw line thru $C$ parallel to $MT$. It will intersect $AD$ at $N$. $AMCN$ is a parallelogram so $CM=AN=ND$. The line $CN$ will intersect $DT$ at $U$. $CU \perp DT$. $NU$ is also a midline in $\triangle ATD$ so $DU=UT$.

Thus, $CU$ is a median and a height in $\triangle CTD$ and $\triangle CTD$ is isosceles.